# incompatible type exception while getting Map object

Tags: java, compiler-errors, hashmap, incompatibletypeerror

I am working on java based application. I have a Map which i want to store in ehcache and retrieve it later.Below is the code.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("1","AAA");
map.put("2","BBB");

final Cache cache = getCache(); // creating the cache object
cache.removeAll();
cache.put(new Element("myMap", map));//Storing the java.util.Map object in Cache
//to get the cache
final Element ele = cache.get("myMap");
Map<String,String> map = (ele == null ? null : ele);
```

Its throwing me the below error

```
incompatible types. found net.sf.ehcache.Element required java.util.Map<String,String>
```

Please advice how can i store the Map object in ehcache and get that element.

Comment: Aside: what exactly do you intend with `(ele == null ? null : ele)`? That's much the same as just `ele`.

Comment: I want to get the myMap object which i stored in Cache, if ele is not null returning the ele which has map object stored. @AndyTurner

Comment: I've never used ehcache but a quick look at the Javadoc for the [Element](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/Element.html) class shows that it has getObjectKey and getObjectValue methods.  I would guess you may be able to get your map using the getObjectValue method and casting to Map<String, String>

Comment: You created a Map.  Then you created an Element.  They are two different objects of completely different types.

Comment: @ToddDunlap - exactly..i need to use getObjectValue method but how can i cast to Map<String,String>, please advice.

Comment: map = (Map<String, String>) ele.getObjectValue();

If this works, let me know and I'll submit an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Your code comment states you're storing a map, yet your code stores an Element. It should not be a surprise that an Element is not a map.

See the docs for http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/3.1.3/org/ehcache/Cache.html#put-K-V-, they're pretty clear:

```
cache.put("myMap", map);
```

I'm not actually entirely sure how your code compiled. There does not appear to be a version of put that takes a single parameter.

Comment: No it still gives me the below error found net.sf.ehcache.Element required java.util.Map<String,String> even when i used cache.put("myMap",map)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confuse in the nested Maps you have ( your Map and EhCache map).

So basically when you do { cache.put(new Element("myMap", map)) } you are adding in ehcache map one entry with id: "myMap" and value your 'map'. However technically this entry is a single object of type 'Element' which encapsulate a key and value in ehcache.

For retrieving back you would retrieve an Element again ( it's what you've inserted ) and from this element get the value ( which is a map ). check below:

```
final Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("123"); // creating the cache object
cache.removeAll();
cache.put(new Element("myMap", map));//Storing the java.util.Map object in Cache
// get your element back
final Element ele = cache.get("myMap");
// get the value of our object. ehcache works with generic objects so you need tocache to your map. Doing a cast since it works with generic object

map = (Map<String, String>) ele.getObjectValue();
```

I would advice for this kind of problem you can just debug your code and check what data is inside your objects. Then you can easily figure out what is happening.